# How to create customized ESLint rules?

Tags: node.js, eslint

Sorry for this newbie question but I could not find the infomation on the net:
I want to develop my own ESLint rules. For that I want to set up an environment in Webstorm. 
EsLint is an node.js project and  I need to access code from other modules. Can somebody give me a hint how to set up everythin that I can develop a custom rule and test ist. 
I am not really familiar with node.js maybe that is allready the problem - i do not know how to access the node.js modules. Locally in my workspace or the central installation of the node.exe that I am starting?

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/eslint/generator-eslint as a starting point for development of the custom rules. You would need locally installed Node.js and NPM. You will also need to install Yeoman using NPM (`npm install -g yo`) and then follow the instructions on the generator-eslint page.
That will create a template for a custom eslint plugin. To create rules and use external modules, you will need to install those modules first, again, using NPM and save them to the `package.json` file (using `npm install ... --save` command). After that you should be able to `require` those modules inside of you rule. There are plenty of eslint plugins out there, that you can look at for an example:

- https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react
- https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular
- https://github.com/ilyavolodin/eslint-plugin-backbone

After you are done, you will need to publish your plugin to NPM to be able to use it.

Comment: Is creating a plugin mandatory for creating the rule?